# Writing a R function that takes in user input file path, then writing them out to csv?

Tags: r, function

The following is a part of the R script that I wrote that takes in files in dta and sav format, then converts them into csvs

```
##### Reading in the data ####

#Sometimes you may need to load in multiple files and merge them. Loading in second 
# dta and merging process has been commented out
dta_data <- read_dta("/ihme/limited_use/IDENT/PROJECT_FOLDERS/UNICEF_MICS/UZB/2021_2022/UZB_MICS6_2021_2022_HH_Y2022M12D27.DTA")
#dta_data_2 <- read_dta("/ihme/limited_use/IDENT/PROJECT_FOLDERS/WB_LSMS_ISA/MWI/2019_2020/MWI_LSMS_ISA_IHS5_2019_2020_HH_GEOVARIABLES_Y2022M10D26.DTA")
#merged_MWI <- merge(dta_data, dta_data_2, by = "ea_id", all.x = TRUE)
write_csv(x=dta_data, path = "UZB_MICS6_2021_2022_HH_Y2022M12D27.csv")

#This loads in SAV files, as well as checking where the output will be saved. 
sav_data <- read_sav("/home/j/DATA/WB_LSMS/JAM/2012/JAM_JSLC_2012_ANNUAL_Y2022M11D29.SAV")
getwd() # this is the folder it will save into unless you specify otherwise in the path below
write_csv(x=sav_data, path="JAM_JSLC_2012_ANNUAL_Y2022M11D29.csv")
```

I want to re-structure this bit to take in user input on where the original files are, and where they should written out to be. And I am not quite sure how to do this. I want to have a if else function where R determines whether the input_file is in dta or sav format. then, depending on the format either use read_dta or read_sav, save that to dta_or_sav, and finally write those out as csvs and save it out to output_path

I got some rough ideas;

```
convert_to_csv <- function(input_file, output_path) {
  dta_or_sav <- read_dta(input_file) 
  write_csv(x=dta_or_sav, path=output_path)       
}
```

I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function that you want with `grepl`, which check the pattern of the file (`.DTA` or `.SAV`).

```
library(haven)
convert_to_csv <- function(input_file, output_path) {
  # .DTA -> read_dta()
  # .SAV -> read_sav()
  if(grepl('.DTA',input_file)){
    input <- read_dta(input_file) 
  } else {
    input <- read_sav(input_file) 
  }
  # Export to CSV 
  write.csv(x=input, path=output_path)       
}
```

Note that `output_path` should contains filename(ends with `.csv`) with your target path.

Comment: Holy cow, that looks way more cleaner than what I had!

Two other things I wanted to consider; 

Print a warning message if the file is neither a dta or sav

And when writing out to csv, drop the ".dta" or ".sav"